# name of a shape

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let *P* be a point, not the center, in the interior of a (round) disk *D*⊂ℝ² and let *A* and *B* be points on ∂*D* such that the line segments *AP* and *BP* have equal length. Choose an arc *AB*. What's the shape bounded by the arc and the two segments called?

Comment: For $P$ at the center, that's a "sector". ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector ) I don't know of a name for $P$ elsewhere. How about "pseudo-sector" or "generalized sector"? (BTW, this might be a cleaner description: Given P on the diameter bisecting arc AB, the figure bounded by AP, BP, and arc AB.)

Comment: What leads you to believe that this object should have a name?

Comment: I call this a "slice" ;)

Comment: @Jasper Loy "By '(round) disk' do you simply mean circle", well, a circle is one-dimensional; I meant the thing it bounds.

Comment: @Day Late Don "a cleaner description": Yes, thanks!

Comment: Well, I like "Carl".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could call it an isosceles curvilinear triangle, although that doesn't capture the curvy part being an arc of a circle.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a [circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

**Edited to add:** As Jasper has pointed out in the comments, this is not what the question asked. So I don't know the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a circular segment is only the region between a chord AB and minor arc AB.

Comment: @Isaac: Yes, my Wikipedia link agrees with you. It looks as if the region between a chord AB and major arc AB doesn't have a name. How about 'circular cosegment'?

Comment: If you "don't know the answer", please delete your answer.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I don't know what inspired you to check back through almost three years of my answers, but I'm sure it's not healthy...

Comment: @TonyK Someone else did. It showed up in the [10k Tools](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools). Rest assured, it's nothing personal.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty. +1